# How can I go to new screen(Intent) after logging successfully in Facebook android

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on a android application in which I need to open a `Facebook login window` and then after logging successfully, `I need to move to another intent (or new screen)`.

So as soon as user is logged in successfully, it should go to another screen in my app. I am having a very hard time making this thing to work. I have got the sample examples from the Facebook SDK so I was testing it out on those examples, I created another screen named `Screen2.java(new xml file)` having only a single button just to test it out.

So in my case what it should do is as soon as you are logged in successfully it should go to .`Screen2 intent`. So I made some changes in the `Main.java class` mentioned here in this [tutorial](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-facebook-integration/) but it is not working for me. Meaning as soon as I am logged in to Facebook, it doesn't goes to `.Screen2 intent` that I have created. Can anyone help me out here?

I made changes only in `Main.java class` as below by adding `new Intent` in the method `onAuthSucceed()`-

```
public class SampleAuthListener implements AuthListener {

    @Override
    public void onAuthSucceed() {
        mText.setText("You have logged in! ");
        // mRequestButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // mUploadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // mPostButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Screen2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthFail(String error) {
        mText.setText("Login Failed: " + error);
    }
}
```

NOTE:- I am able to login into Facebook but after logging successfully, it doesn't goes to my new Intent.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the impression you needed something like this

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Logged in...");
        //fire intent
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks cplain for the help, So in which class I need to modify? You provided the above code from the tutorial I mentioned? Or it's just your thoughts? If you can provide me some help basis on the tutorial I provided then I can understand better or if there is any other tutorial in which this code is there then I can look into that code as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is where I started on my own projects: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#prerequisities and customized from there

Comment: One more quick question. I am not able to understand how can I add the Facebook SDK to my project after going through that tutorial? Can you explain me in a simple way? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Assuming you're using Eclipse, to attach it all you do is download the SDK, import it into your workspace then right click on your project go properties/Android then under Library hit add and point to the SDK. Then you have access to all the classes etc

Comment: Why should I import all the projects into my workspace, I cannot import any libraries for this?

Comment: just the sdk, you don't need the samples

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22872/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-cplain)